# Check if autocad 2014 is open

Tags: autocad, autolisp

We have recently switched from autocad 2010 to autocad 2014, and are encountering some annoying problems. Every drawing we open, is now opening in a separate application. So, instead of multiple drawings per application, it is opening each and every one in a single window..

When opening drawing from our datamanager, we check if an application of autocad 2010 is running through the following line of code:

```
(setq ddeconv (ddeinitiate "AutoCAD.r18.DDE" "System" ))
```

What is the equivalent of this code for autocad 2014? Or, simply put, how do we check if the autocad 2014 is already running?

Note that I am a complete novice in LISP, so if you require more code or information, please leave a comment!

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is your application in Lisp or AutoLisp?

If it's in AutoLisp, you already know AutoCAD is running as your application is running.  If it's Lisp, you can check if the AutoCAD process is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying, I've found the answer myself. It seems it was as simple as changing the release version from 18 to 19, becoming:

```
(setq ddeconv (ddeinitiate "AutoCAD.r18.DDE" "System" ))
```